# How to tick 1 check-box to select all check box's in html Table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am making a aspx page I have 3 html tables, dynamically I am adding check-boxes to each cell. Here I have another check-box for every table(out side table), if I check the check-box then I want to check all check-boxes in the corresponding html table, here I am using some script to check. But if I select one then all check-boxes in the page(checked 3 tables check-boxes) are also selected. How can I solve this issue?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


   <script src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">         
           function checkAll(bx) {
               var cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
               for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
                   if (cbs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                       cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
                   }
               }
           }
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>       
    <h1>Adjs</h1>
        <h4>Select All</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" id="chk1" />
           <table id="tbl1" runat="server" border="1">                
            <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>  <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <h1>chgs</h1>
          <h4>Select All</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" id="chk2" />
        <table id="tbl" runat="server" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>  <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <br />
         <h1>Pmts</h1>
          <h4>Select All</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" id="chk3" />
        <table id="Table1" runat="server" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>  <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <br />
        <div class="cls1">
            <h2>Select Condition</h2>
       <table id="Table2" runat="server" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>  <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below code is adding checkboxs dynamically(using C#)

```
Label objLabel = new Label();                  
                    CheckBox chk1 = new CheckBox();
                    objLabel.ID = "lbladj" + i.ToString();
                    objLabel.Text = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    chk1.ID = "chk" + objLabel.Text;
                    Form.Controls.Add(objLabel);
                    Form.Controls.Add(chk1);
                    if (Column < 5)
                    {
                        tbl1.Rows[Row].Cells[Column].Controls.Add(objLabel);
                        tbl1.Rows[Row].Cells[Column].Controls.Add(chk1);

                        Column++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Row++;
                        Column = 0;
                        tbl1.Rows[Row].Cells[Column].Controls.Add(objLabel);
                        tbl1.Rows[Row].Cells[Column].Controls.Add(chk1);
                        Column++;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the next immediate element of the current element.

> [`:checkbox`](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) => *Selects all elements of type checkbox*
>
> [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) => *Set one or more properties for the set of matched elements*
>   Try this:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution. I have used next() method as per your html structure and then select all checkbox.

```
jQuery(':checkbox[id^="chk2"]').on('click', function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if($this.is(':checked')) {
         $this.next('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
         $this.next('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: hi kp singh..thnq for your quick response. Here how can write clickevent for checkbox or how can pass id's?

Comment: I have updated the answer. using [id^="chk"], you can target all checkbox having IDs start with chk

Answer (score 0):

> You can alternatively give the **main checkbox an id(mainid)** and all others a **custom class(CustomClass)**. On main checkbox click , make all other checkbox value true .
>        For the next table give **another class(CustomClass2)** so that it is **not checked** and only checkbox with  **$('CustomClass') is checked**

`$('#mainid').on('click', function()
 { 
    $('CustomClass').attr("checked", true); 
 });`

> OR
>   Use closest

`$('#chk1').click(function(e){
    var table= $(e.target).closest('table');
    $('td input:checkbox',table).prop('checked',this.checked);
});`